# Rsyslog to direct log messages to local syslog host on port 5000 using TCP

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

I have configured the below filter for rsyslog to direct a few SSH messages to a specific TCP port 5000 on the local system, so that the service running on the 5000 will process the SSH messages further.

```
if $fromhost-ip == '127.0.0.1' and ( ($msg contains 'SSH') and ($msg contains 'Test') ) then @@127.0.0.1:5000
```

Everything seems fine, but the messages are not redirected to the port 5000 and if we direct the messages to UDP port it is working fine.

Below is the filter for messages directing to UDP port.

```
if $fromhost-ip == '127.0.0.1' and ( ($msg contains 'SSH') and ($msg contains 'Test') ) then @127.0.0.1:5000
```

Could you please let me know, why TCP port do not work and UDP port works.

Comment: Maybe a firewall is getting in the way. Does `telnet 127.0.0.1 5000` connect successfully or give an error?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, Telnet is working fine. 
root@blr09> telnet 127.0.0.1 5000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]
telnet>

Comment: Can you verify that rsyslog is actually listening to the port? `netstat -tnlp | grep rsyslog`? Then make sure that firewall is configured too (i.e., in fedora): `firewall-cmd --zone=zone --add-port=5000/tcp`

Comment: @arash, rsyslog is running on UDP port.

root@blr09> netstat -nlp | grep rsyslog
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27129           0.0.0.0:*                           11218/rsyslogd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:29046           0.0.0.0:*                           11218/rsyslogd

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can use *tunneling* for this. For example

```
ssh username@serverAddress -L 5000:11.22.33.44:80

    # username - username on server
    # serverAddress - server address
    # 8080: - port on the local machine that will be opened on loopback interface (127.0.0.1)
    # 11.22.33.44 - IP address of the server that we'll create a tunnel to using SSH
```

Look here for more info: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-tunneling-on-a-vps

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

May be you decide to use RELP? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_Event_Logging_Protocol)

As described at https://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyslog.conf

you need to replace your
"then @127.0.0.1:5000"
to
"then :omrelp:127.0.0.1:5000"

Comment: i am getting below error when i add omrelp and restart rsyslog.

"Mar  2 04:40:31 blr09 rsyslogd-2207: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/atl_security.conf, on or before line 1: errors occured in file '/etc/rsyslog.d/atl_security.conf' around line 1 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2207 ]"

root@blr09> cat /etc/rsyslog.d/atl_security.conf
if $fromhost-ip == '127.0.0.1' and ( ($msg contains 'SSH') and ($msg contains 'Test') ) then :omrelp:127.0.0.1:5000
root@blr09>

Comment: Can you please provide output of rsyslogd -v

Comment: root@blr09> rsyslogd -v
rsyslogd 7.4.7, compiled with:
        FEATURE_REGEXP:                         Yes
        FEATURE_LARGEFILE:                      No
        GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:              Yes
        FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
        32bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        64bit Atomic operations supported:      Yes
        Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
        uuid support:                           Yes

See http://www.rsyslog.com for more information.
root@blr09>

Comment: Hm! I supposed you use v8. Ok, let's start from the beginning http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v7-stable/configuration/index.html As I understand you need another replacement: "then @@127.0.0.1:5000"

Comment: Could you please explain more about the replacement.

Comment: As I undersnand rsyslog version 7 syntax: @127.0.0.1:5000 == proto=UDP, host=127.0.0.1, port=5000.  And the doubling @  as this: @@127.0.0.1:5000 - switches proto to TCP